# SQL SERVER 2008. How to select one row only based on dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Select MIN([appdate]), CustID, CustAtt, Surname, Firstname, itemType
From table 
Where appDate > (getdate())
Group by CustID, CustAtt

CustAtt CustID  Surname Firstname   appDate      itemType
 53247   20675    A        AX       
 49535   12/FX08  B        BX      14/08/2017     solid
 70433   400039   C        CX       
 67119   413555   D        DX       
 51406   27/EY07  E        EX      14/07/2017     Liquid
 51406   27/EY08  E        EX      13/09/2017     Gas
 51406   27/EY09  E        EX      11/12/2017     Solid A
 51406   27/EY10  E        EX      06/06/2018     Liquid A
 82820   410053   F        FX       
 52395   29/FA72  G        GX      25/09/2017     Gas A
 89488   414282   H        HX       
 55855   412799   I        IX      30/08/2017     Solid 
 55855   412799   I        IX      21/08/2017     Liquid
 53248   16/EK15  J        JX      06/07/2017     Gas
 53248   16/EK15  J        JX      17/07/2017     Solid B
 89835   911528   K        KX      08/05/2018     Solid B
```

The above is a snippet of my output from the above script,  but isn't giving me the desired output. I want to only select one row for each CustID & CustAtt from my dataset based on the appdate column.

The desired output should include the next earliest date from current date, in the case the dates are the same any given row is acceptable:
The output table should yield:

```
CustAtt CustID  Surname Firstname   appDate      itemType
 53247   20675    A        AX       
 49535   12/FX08  B        BX      14/08/2017     solid
 70433   400039   C        CX       
 67119   413555   D        DX       
 51406   27/EY07  E        EX      14/07/2017     Liquid
 82820   410053   F        FX       
 52395   29/FA72  G        GX      25/09/2017     Gas A
 89488   414282   H        HX       
 55855   412799   I        IX      21/08/2017     Liquid
 53248   16/EK15  J        JX      06/07/2017     Gas
 89835   911528   K        KX      08/05/2018     Solid B
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c35e2/1

```
create table t(
    id int,
    x int,
    y int,
    z int,
    a int,
    b int,
    c datetime
);


-- Build t table
INSERT INTO t values
(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, getdate()),
(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, dateadd(hh,+3,getdate())),
(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, dateadd(hh,+1,getdate())),
(4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, dateadd(hh,+2,getdate())),
(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, dateadd(hh,-2,getdate())),
(6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, dateadd(hh,-1,getdate())),
(7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, dateadd(hh,+1,getdate())),
(8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, dateadd(hh,+1,getdate())),
(9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, dateadd(hh,+1,getdate()));

select top 1 t.id, s.*, t.c 
from t
join (
    select x,y,z,a,b
    from t
    group by x,y,z,a,b
    having count(*) > 1
) s 
on s.x = t.x
    and s.y = t.y
    and s.z = t.z
    and s.a = t.a
    and s.b = t.b
    and (getdate() < t.c)
order by t.c
```

Comment: I would like to return only one record for each ID. Currently multiple rows are returned for the same ID because each person can come in for an appointment on different dates. I want to select all the data where only one record for each person is displayed where the date is the earliest date from current date. Eg if I have 2 records of the same person with different dates (07/07/17 and 08/07/17) I want the earliest from current date that is the 07/07/17 only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HAVING keyword. It can filter "after group".

```
SELECT
 MIN([appdate]), 
 id, 
 type
FROM
 [table]
WHERE
 appdate > GETDATE()
GROUP BY
 id, type
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) > 1 -- select only records, that have duplicates, based on our "group by"
ORDER BY
 id
```

***added 12.07.17:***
(for revised question)

Count row number (partion by CustID & CustAtt, order by appDate) and then select first one for each one.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        *, 
        Row_number() OVER( 
          PARTITION BY CustID, CustAtt ORDER BY appDate
        ) row_number
    FROM
        table
    ) 
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  cte
WHERE
  row_number = 1
```

Comment: Your suggested method still returns duplicate ID.

Comment: so, you need *all* not duplicates records and "*last one*" for each duplicates (by CustAtt & CustID)?

Comment: I have revised my initial question please have a look.